# Database Mirroring Properties Page Missing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having a problem with one database on my SQL Server 2005 production server.

A number of databases are already set up for mirroring, however when I right click and go to properties in SSMS, on one particular database there is no "Mirroring" property page available.

I have done the normal tasks, such as setting Full Recovery model, running a full backup of the database and backing up the logs.

I can't see that this is a server specific issue as other databases are happily mirroring.

I've looked around and I can't see that I'm missing a setting, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: This is nothing to do with the Mirror Database yet, I can't get as far as specifying the Mirror Database, I cannot see the "Mirroring" page on the principal.

EDIT: I have managed to set up mirroring using t-sql commands. However I am still unable to see the "Mirroring Page".

UPDATE: This applies to the Transaction Log Shipping option as well. I can successfully set it up in SQL but not through SSMS.

Comment: How many databases are you mirroring in one instance?

Comment: I was mirroring 7 databases, I'm now down to 1. The problem is not specific to mirroring, I can't get access to the the Transaction Log Shipping page either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to have a Microsoft Support call for the problem I was facing. Anyway after sometime and a number of support sessions they worked out that the database with the problem had an ID of 4 in sys.databases. IDs 1-4 are usually reserved for the system databases and if a database has any of these ids the T-log or Mirroring properties are not displayed. So somehow are database got the ID 3 and now I better get on and detach and reattach some databases to reassign IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I have been caught out by SSMS respecting database permissions and not showing options for some users previously. Are you connected with server admin permissions or as a less privileged user?

Just a thought ...
Jonathan

Comment: It's a nice thought, unfortunately no good. Tried logging in as sa and no luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact symptoms, although I didn't have any databases setup with mirroring. I ultimately couldn't find documentation to support my solution, but it worked for me.

I had SSMS - Basic installed. After I uninstalled it and installed SSMS - Complete instead, Mirroring and Transaction Log Shipping are now visible entries in the Properties page.

Microsoft only says the following about ADV_SSMS, which seems to be inadequate given what I learned:

Installs SQL Server Management Tools – Complete. This includes the following components in addition to the components in the Basic version:

- SQL Server Management Studio support for Reporting Services, Analysis Services, and Integration Services
- SQL Server Profiler
- Database Engine Tuning Advisor